# Mark Project Items as Embedded Resource by file type

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, embedded-resource, projects-and-solutions

I have an asp.net MVC project that I reference in other projects and for certain file types (cshtml, images, css etc). In order to include certain file types I always have to remember to select 'Embedded Resource' as the build action for each file. Is there a way to do this automatically?

I remember seeing a snippet of code on the web somewhere that allowed you to do this by modifying your project file, but after a lot of searching I can't seem to find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally tracked down the blog where I had seen this, you can find it [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/04/05/mvc-portable-areas-ndash-static-files-as-embedded-resources.aspx).

I needed to add a BeforeBuild action to the csproj file to include the embedded resources.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
       <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.cshtml;**\*.png;**\*.jpg;**\*.svg;**\*.ico;**\*.swf;**\*.gif;**\*.css;**\*.js;**\*.woff;**\*.eot;**\*.ttf;" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I also had to change the files I already had included as 'embedded content' back to 'content' otherwise they were included twice.